# Disable disk cache on media foundation network source

Tags: http, caching, mp4, ms-media-foundation, multimedia

I'm currently using MediaFoundation to read MP4 video from a remote server using HTTP. I create the media source using the source resolver method `CreateObjectFromURL`.

This works perfectly fine and the video is great, except for one huge pain point:

All data received by the source seems to be cached to disk, specifically in `...AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE`. This is not ideal as the streams can be open for an unlimited amount of time because the video is live.

At the moment the only real solution is to periodically disconnect, clean up temporary internet files, then reconnect again. This would need to be done every few hours to stop the machine from filling up and exploding. It is not really an acceptable long term solution for the end user of course.

I have tried to disable caching by setting the `MFNETSOURCE_CACHEENABLED` attribute on the media source to false, but it doesn't seem to stop it caching at all.

Is there a trick I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: Do you use IPropertyStore to specify MFNETSOURCE_CACHEENABLED: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206738(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, that's right. I pass configuration values to the method on the source resolver. It works for other things but it appears the underlying http bytestream doesn't honour this cache setting. I have a horrible feeling that it simply doesn't support streaming, and is just treating the stream as a partially downloaded MP4 file and caching it in order to support seeking etc. Assuming the worst, I'm currently implementing a custom http mediasource. It's quite a bit of work though so still holding on for a quicker solution ;)

Comment: I was also going to recommend you a custom HTTP media source using IOCP for instance.